# Is there a reason why a Salesforce User might be unable to select the report "Subscribe" button?

Tags: reporting

I have a user with a Salesforce(System Admin) license who is unable to select the Subscribe button on any report. However, users with Salesforce Platform licenses seem to be able to do so. I was hoping someone might know how to adjust permissions to allow this user to Subscribe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and this is a good Success community answer. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DAtdAAG

So in summary

- Setup | Customize | Reports & Dashboards | Report Notifications - Enable
- Setup | Mobile Administration | Notifications | Settings - In App Notifications
- Ensure it's not a Standard Report

Also - coming in Lightning in Spring '17.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce only allows users to Subscribe upto 5 reports. The subscribe button is disabled after subscribing to 5 reports.

The user should first unsubscribe from older subscriptions before signing up for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Also, some report types appear not to support subscription. An Opportunities with Historical Trending report I created recently does not display a Subscribe button.